# How to find particular character in string

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to find the char index of a letter in a string,
for example if have the input string like 'K#,K+,K'. The issue is it is printing 1.

```
declare @input nvarchar(100) = 'K#,K+,K'
if charindex('K', @input) > 0
begin print charindex('K', @input) end
else print 0 

Output
1
```

Comment: well, it is one? what you expected?

Comment: can we search for exact character, am expecting output like 3

Comment: So you are searching for a field in CSV that matches the character?

Comment: @John are you using SQL Sever?

Comment: What else should that query print? **Why** should it print 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are having CSV and need to find a particular element in this list. You need to split the values first.

```
SELECT [ordinal]
FROM STRING_SPLIT('K#,K+,K', ',', 1)
WHERE [value] = 'K'
```

The above will work on SQL Server 2022. For previous version you can use the following:

```
DECLARE @input nvarchar(100) = 'K#,K+,K';
DECLARE @inputXML XML = CAST(N'<r><![CDATA[' + REPLACE(@input, ',', ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + ']]></r>' AS XML);

SELECT [index]
FROM
(
    SELECT T.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(128)')
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T.c)
    FROM @inputXML.nodes('r') T(c)
) DS ([value], [index])
WHERE [value] = 'K'
```